# how do I connect a user to post in React?

Tags: reactjs, mapping

how do I connect a user to their post? the post has the user-id from who posted a review but how do I go about mapping the posts?

this is my post map

```
{post.map(post => (
                    <Post key={post.id} post={post} />
                ))}
```

fname and address are from user, post is from the list of posts
and post file:

```
{fname}
{address}
{post}
```

so I have the list of posts and the lists of users, they are separate
but the post has the user id of who posted it but how do I connect them?
mapping through the post and when the userid from the user is equivalent to the userid from the post filter it or something?
how do I connect them through that relationship?

something I'm going for but it gives an error user.post is undefined

```
 {post.map(post => (
                <Post
                    key={post.id}
                    food={post}
                    user={user.filter(
                        user => 
                        user.post.userid)}
                />
            ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I set the value for the user in the post tag as below, it worked for me.

```
    <Post
        key={post.id}
        food={post}
        user={users.find(
            user => 
            post.userid === user.id //if you have an users array here you should use find instead of filter and then try to match the post.userid with user.id.
        )}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

as post has `userid` and user has `id` then you can solve it with something like this:

```
  {post.map((post) => (
    <Post
      key={post.id}
      food={post}
      user={user.find((u) => u.id === post.userid)}
    />
  ))}
```